# Ноутбук для Android разработки

Tags: ноутбук

подскажите пожалуйста какой в данный момент наилучший ноутбук для андроид разработки(Android studio), по цене в пределах 1000 евро, или просто какие характеристики важнее всего, в компьютерах разбираюсь на пользовательском уровне поэтому спрашиваю, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Я думаю i5+8г оперативы будет за глаза. Есть пару хороших вариантов:

1. Xiaomi Mi Notebook pro
2. ASUS Zenbook(UX433FA)
3. HUAWEI MateBook(UX433FA)
4. Быушный macbook air 2018

Лично я бы выбрал HUAWEI, ну или уже добавил 5к р. и купил в интернет магазине Macbook air. его можно купить за 75к.

Comment: @Данил Сычев Обращайтесь. Можно меточку поставить ;)

Comment: я сразу нажал)) но выскакивает "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."

Answer (score 0):

Все, что важно в ноутбуке это процессор и оперативка. Процессор минимум i5, оперативки минимум 8 гб. Могу посоветовать Xiaomi Mi Notebook pro 15,6 в минимальной комплектации i5/8гб, SSD 256 гб , видеокарта MX150, которая много не кушает(и для программиста она не важна) стоит около 1000$. В данной ценовой категории это самый лучший вариант, из тех, что предлагают.

Comment: почему заминусили комментарий? не могли бы вы не просто ставить минус, но еще и подсказывать в чем ошибка, потому что просто от минуса толку маловато